# PHP CodeIgniter - PayPerClick

Tags: php, codeigniter

im trying to design a catalog website that will display a client's restaurant's menu. each item is linked to a details page about that item. my goal is to implement a system that will help me gather stats about which items are of interest to my users. im using codeigniter for development. the system should be able to address the following:

- each time a search query is run and relevant menu items (plus pictures) are displayed, it should log a count for each item how many times it was displayed (impression count).
- each time a user clicks an image to go to the details page, it should log a count for each item how many times it was clicked (click thru count).
- i will be emailing the website's subscriber list about promotions and new deals (including pictures). the system should log how many emails were opened and images seen (impression count).
- if a user clicks the link in the email to come to my website's details page, the system should log a click-thru count.

as i understand, the process that should be followed is as follows:

1. make a controller that accepts an image/page identifier and a code.
2. the controller would look in the database for this ID.
3. if it finds one, it would increment its impression count (if its an image) or click-thru count (if its a link to a page) depending on the code included in the href.
4. the controller returns the actual image data or page path associated with the ID.

**sample paths:**

- image path: http://www.mysite.com/assets/newdish.jpg
- details page: http://www.mysite.com/details/newdish

**sample email:**

```
hi, check this new dish out!
<a href="http://www.mysite.com/details/newdish/linkedbyemail">
    <img src="http://www.mysite.com/images/12345">
</a>
```

the `Details` controller would load the view indicated by `newdish` and if the `linkedbyemail` parameter is set, it'll log a click count too. the `Images` controller will find the ID `12345` in database, log an impression count, and return the image data.

the options i might have are:

- use google analytics (somehow) with my site to count how many banners are served and clicked. i dont know how flexible this is since i need to gather stats per image / page. and whether the page was reached from an email or directly. if google does allow such collection, that that's the best thing i could ask for.
- use a code igniter spark / library that handles these sort of requirements. ive searched a lot but havent found one. if you can help me here, it'll be great.
- roll out my own stats mechanism. if the two options above arent possible then i would have to do this. i think i have the basic idea right here. if there's something else that i need to keep in mind to implement this, please tell me.

once again, i need the ability to log who (how many users) are accessing my pages/images and from where (email / directly / or linked by an external website).

thanks..

Comment: just curious why you want to implement pay-per-click on restaurant menu? Don't really understand. Can easily do with CI though.

Comment: @WayneTunMyint.. as a way to determine which items the target audience is more interested in.. ive really oversimplified the system to keep things simple here.. but the goal is the same.. to use a pay-per-click system..

Comment: @AweSIM As in the users would pay to view your menu?

Comment: @Sam.. please see the latest edit on the question.

Comment: will it store  daily,monthly,yearly visits/clicks

Comment: itll store timestamps with each access (plus maybe useragent, etc).. generating daily, monthly or yearly reports from that shouldnt be too hard.. so yes.. =)

Comment: you want make stats about menu visits, sell advertising to your clients and keep track of your email campaign. Right ?

Comment: @lighta.. exactly.. =).. please feel free to edit the question to rephrase the problem statement better.. by the amount of questioning comments im getting, im thinking i didnt use correct terminology..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first off.. my apologies for not searching thru the forum more thoroughly.. i did come across a number of articles that helped me reach the solution (none of them directly though).. anyways, here's my solution..

**Assets Table**

- ID (int, primary, auto inc)
- Path (string)
- ImpressionCount (int)

**Assets_model Model**

- GetPathByID ($iID) -> returns the actual path of them image with the given ID
- AddImpression ($iID) -> increments the impression count of the row with the given ID

**SimAssets Library**

```
class SimAssets
{
    const C_ASSETS_CONTROLLER = 'assets/index';

    public function GetTrackingAsset ($iImageID)
    {
        $sLink = sprintf('%s/%s/%u', config_item('base_url'), self::C_ASSETS_CONTROLLER, $iImageID);
        return $sLink;
    }
}
```

**Assets Controller**

```
class Assets extends CI_Controller
{
    public function index ($sID)
    {
        $iID = intval($sID);
        $this->load->model ('assets_model');
        $sPath = $this->assets_model->GetPathByID($iID);
        if ($sPath !== NULL)
        {
            if (file_exists($sPath))
            {
                $this->assets_model->AddImpression ($sID);
                header (sprintf('Content-Length: %u',                           filesize($sPath)));
                header (sprintf('Content-Type: %s',                             'image/jpg'));
                header (sprintf('Content-Disposition: inline; filename=%s',     $sPath));
                echo readfile ($sPath);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
echo '<img src="' . $this->simassets->GetTrackingAsset(3) . '">';

// <img src="http://localhost/Testing/index.php/assets/index/3">
```

**What is being accomplished**

1. every page / email that needs to be tracked would have an embedded link to an image defined as an asset.

   - 1, 1x1.jpg => image used to track a particular email promotion
   - 2, 1x1.jpg => image used to track another particular email promotion
   - 3, 1x1.jpg => image used in all emails to track how many were opened in total
   - 4, DishA_thumb.jpg => image used on the search page to see how many searches displayed this item
   - 5, DishA_large.jpg => image used on the detail page to see how many people actually looked at this item in detail.
2. when a call is made to the `Assets` controller, it finds the path of the image with the given ID, renders it as an image, and increments its impression count.

**What can be done further**

1. ImpressionCount can be removed from the `Assets` table and a new table `AssetTracking` created as follows:

   - AssetID (int)
   - LastAccessed (time_stamp)
   - Tag (string)
2. A second parameter can be added to the asset link that includes a tag (information uniquely identifying a visitor, whether this link appeared on the page or email, etc)
3. AddImpression would simply add a new row in `AssetTracking` table with the given `AssetID` and `Tag`.
4. A similar method can be added to `SimAssets` library that returns page URLs instead of image URLs.
5. Another method can be added to `Assets` controller that checks the passed page ID, logs a hit, and redirects to the actual page URL. This allows me to:

   - send an email with a link including page ID instead of a page URL
   - when users clicks the link, the controller will redirect them to the appropriate page, while logging a hit for the given page ID.

**Combination of the Two Schemes**

create an email:

```
<img src="http://localhost/Test/index.php/assets/image/1/User123" style="display:none">
// actually loads http://localhost/Test/1x1.jpg

Hi, we at XYZ have a new promotion offer for a 
<a href="http://localhost/Test/index.php/assets/pages/1/User123">New Pizza</a>.
Can we tempt you with it? =)
// actually redirects to http://localhost/Test/index.php/items/detail/newpizza
```

when the email renders, it'll log that User123 requested 1x1.jpg (hence read the email). if the user clicks the link to jump to my site, the assets controller will log that User123 reached the given page via email. the possibilities are endless. =)

hope this helps someone.. =)